# similar string from pickle list

Tags: python, search, pickle

I'm looking for a way to check if a user's input is similar to a current string in a pickle file.

For example, say I have a user inputting their name...

```
userInput = input("What's your name? ")
```

... is there a way to check if it's similar to an existing string in a pickle file, kinda like this might do:

```
store = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
simResult = similar(userInput, store)
for userInput not in store:
   print("This user doesn't exist in our database")
   print("How about", simResult, "?")
```

Comment: You seem to be using `pickle.load` correctly, so I don't think your question really has anything to do with pickle. I think your question is actually "how do I determine if a string is similar to any strings in a collection?".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `difflib.SequenceMatcher` :

```
>>> from difflib import SequenceMatcher
>>> 
>>> def similar(a, b):
...     return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
... 
>>> similar('word','words')
0.8888888888888888
>>> similar('word','word')
1.0

>>> for i in word_list : 
...    if similar(test_word,i) > 0.7 : # 0.7 is optional         
            print test_word
```

Comment: I understand that, but how do I use that to find out if there is a similar string in a list?

Comment: @hydrobane you can use it in a loop ! see the edited answer !

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to search a pickled file for a pickle of a string -- and let's throw in the complexity that you might have a huge "database" file of user name strings to search through -- then it might be very costly to try to open the entire file by loading (and thus unpicking) the whole file to check if the string is contained in the file.  It's expensive to unpickle the contents of a huge pickled file.

Since you are looking for a string in a pickled string… there's a very easy way to do it that doesn't require you unpickle your huge file of stored names.

```
# let's make a pickled file of name strings (pretend it's a huge list)
>>> import pickle
>>> names = ["John Cleese", "Graham Chapman", "Michael Palin", \
...          "Eric Idle", "Terry Gilliam", "Terry Jones", "Guido van Rossum"]
>>> f = open('names.pik', 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump(names, f, -1)
>>> f.close()
>>> 
>>> # we can unpickle the file, with load, and compare
>>> f = open('names.pik', 'rb')
>>> people = pickle.load(f)
>>> f.close()
>>> "Guido van Rossum" in people
True
>>> # for big files, this is slow.
>>> # you are searching for lists, so you can just search the file
>>> lines = open('names.pik', 'rb').read()
>>> "Guido van Rossum" in lines
True
>>> # the reason this works is that pickle dumps strings transparently
>>> pickle.dumps("Guido van Rossum")             
"S'Guido van Rossum'\np0\n."
>>> 
>>> pickle.dumps("Guido van Rossum", -1)
'\x80\x02U\x10Guido van Rossumq\x00.'
```

If you are looking for how two strings are similar to each other, but not the same… this is not a question that has anything to do with `pickle` -- and `difflib` (as suggested by @Kasra) is a good choice.